# MongoDB takes seconds to save object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to use Mongoose to save an object to a local MongoDB database. The following code saves a song in a playlist and times it:

```
console.time('saveSong');
playlistSong = await (new PlaylistSong({
  added: new Date(),
  url: song.url,
  title: song.title,
  thumbnail: song.thumbnail,
  duration: song.duration
}).save());
console.timeEnd('saveSong');
```

When this code runs, the output is the following:

```
saveSong: 2021.505ms
```

However, when I look at the profiling logs in the MongoDB server, it says that the insertion execution time is 0ms. What takes so much time in this simple query and how could I improve it?

The model has a simple schema with a few attributes:

```
const playlistSongSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  added: Date,
  addedBy: String,

  removed: Date,
  removedBy: String,

  finished: Date,

  likes: [String],
  dislikes: [String],

  url: String,
  title: String,
  thumbnail: String,
  duration: Date
});
playlistSongSchema.index({ isRemoved: -1, isFinished: 1, added: 1 });

exports.PlaylistSong = mongoose.model('PlaylistSong', playlistSongSchema);
```

**Edit:**

Not only save but find queries also take about 2s to execute.
E.g.

```
console.time('getSong');
let video = await YoutubeVideo.findOne({ videoId });
console.timeEnd('getSong');
```

Output:

```
getSong: 2027.283ms
```

**Edit #2:**

I could reduce the code to:

```
await mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost:27017`);

const testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ testAttr: Boolean });
const TestObject = mongoose.model('TestObject', testSchema);

console.time('save');
await (new TestObject({ testAttr: true }).save());
console.timeEnd('save');

console.time('find');
await TestObject.findOne();
console.timeEnd('find');
```

The output of this is:

```
save: 15.009ms
find: 1015.816ms
```

However, if I save two objects after each other, the save becomes slower and the find speeds up.

```
console.time('save');
await (new TestObject({ testAttr: false }).save());
await (new TestObject({ testAttr: false }).save());
console.timeEnd('save');

console.time('find');
await TestObject.findOne({ testAttr: true });
console.timeEnd('find');
```

Output:

```
save: 1042.974ms
find: 30.846ms
```

Using `mongodb` module instead of `mongoose` have the same results.

Comment: Mongoose does validations, pre events and stuff, show us your model.

Comment: @desoares I added it to the post.

Comment: This is localhost server?

Comment: I tested your mode in my localhost, it took 12ms, tops to save. Your problem is, probably elsewhere. Are you using express?

Comment: Yes, it is a local server and I'm running an express webserver in parallel, but so far I only use this logic manually from a function called from main.js (for testing purposes).

Comment: I added a few more test cases to the question. Can it be that this issue happens because it writes the db to the disk? Few seconds for a disk write still seems a bit slow though.

Comment: Did you try to do exactly the same operations directly in the MongoDB shell?